# Prove the expression by using Quadratic equation's condition

Tags: quadratics

One root of quadratic equation $a*x^2+b*x+c$ is square of another root. Then prove that $c*(a-b)^2 = (b^2-ac)*(a-b)$.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial for MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). What have you tried so far? Where is the difficulty? *Please share some of your thought and/or work.*

Answer (score 0):

By Vieta's relations,

$$-\frac ba=r+r^2,\\\frac ca=r^3$$ and you have to eliminate $r$.

Then

$$1-\frac ba=1+r+r^2=\frac{r^3-1}{r-1}=\frac{\dfrac ca-1}{r-1}$$ gives you $r=\dfrac{c-b}{a-b}$, which you plug in one of the equations.